# I want to calculate spped of android device using accelerometers sensor only not with GPS?

Tags: accelerometer, android-sensors

I need to create an app that Calculates the moving car velocity/speed, with x/y/z speed.

My idea is using device's accelerometer.

I am using Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and getting ax,ay,az (acceleration in x,y,z direction). how to get sped of device. Lots of physics formulas suggested by people to get speed but any one of then not giving correct speed compared to GPS. Please tell me code or good link which solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That would be very difficult. To calculate the speed of the device, you need to calculate the integral of the acceleration. But to do so, you need to very accurately know for very dense points in time both the device's rotation and its acceleration. Assuming you do have those things, you simply need to take the device's initial speed, and for each point in time add to it (rotation matrix * acceleration vector * time to next measurement). That's probably the most accurate thing you can that is simple enough.